# Why is a variable I've already defined showing up as "not defined" in Python?

Tags: python

I am testing a code written and posted on the website

http://foreverlearning.altervista.org/genetic-programming-symbolic-regression-pt-3/

The portion of the code is located at the bottom part of the webpage. When running the test code mainpova.py, I am getting the syntax error.

The syntax error is,

```
python mainprova4.py
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "mainprova4.py", line 1, in <module>
 import generation as gn
 File "/home/adam/DocumentsNew2/MathCode/SymbolicRegression/WebpageCode /generation.py", line 105, in <module>
  for i in range(0, numCrossover):
  NameError: name 'numCrossover' is not defined
```

The code for this is,

```
import random as rnd
import generator as gtr
import treeOperations as trop

class Generation(object):
def __init__(self):
self.membersWithErrors = []

def addMember(self, member):
  """ Add a tree to the generation """
  self.membersWithErrors.append([member, 0])

def setMember(self, member, index):
  """ Updates the member at the specified position """
   self.membersWithErrors[index] = member

def setError(self, index, error):
""" Sets the error of the member at the specified position """
  self.membersWithErrors[index][1] = error

def getMember(self, index):
""" Returns the member at the specified position """
  return self.membersWithErrors[index][0]

def getError(self, index):
""" Returns the error of the member at the specified position """
  return self.membersWithErrors[index][1]

def size(self):
""" Returns the number of members curently in the generation """
  return len(self.membersWithErrors)

def clear(self):
""" Clears the generation, i.e. removes all the members """
  self.membersWithErrors.clear()

def sort(self, descending):
""" Sorts the members of the generation according the their score """
  self.membersWithErrors.sort(key = lambda l: l[1], reverse = descending)

def getMembersForReproduction(self, numMembers, pickProb):
""" Returns a certain number of distinct members from the generation.
 The first member is selected with probability pickProb. If it's not          chosen, the 
  second member is selected with probability pickProb, and so on. """
  selectedMembers = []
  while len(selectedMembers) < numMembers: 
    indexSelected = 0  
    while rnd.randint(0, 100) > int(pickProb * 100) and indexSelected !=           len(self.membersWithErrors) - 1:
indexSelected += 1
memberWithErrorSelected = self.membersWithErrors[indexSelected]
if memberWithErrorSelected[0] not in selectedMembers:
   selectedMembers.append(memberWithErrorSelected[0])
return selectedMembers 

def next(self, crossoverPerc, mutationPerc, randomPerc, copyPerc,        shouldPruneForMaxHeight, minHeight, maxHeight, minValue, maxValue,   variables, operators):
""" It proceeds to the next generation with the help of genetic   operations """
oldMembersWithError = self.membersWithErrors
newMembersWithError = []
maxMembers = len(oldMembersWithError)
numCrossover = int(maxMembers * crossoverPerc)
numMutation = int(maxMembers * mutationPerc)
numRandom = int(maxMembers * randomPerc)
numCopy = maxMembers - numCrossover - numMutation - numRandom

# Crossover
for i in range(0, numCrossover):
 members = self.getMembersForReproduction(2, 0.3)
 m1 = members[0]
 m2 = members[1]
 newMember = trop.crossover(m1, m2)
 newMembersWithError.append([newMember, 0])

# Mutation
for i in range(0, numMutation):
 m1 = self.getMembersForReproduction(1, 0.3)[0]
 newMembersWithError.append([trop.mutation(m1, minValue, maxValue, variables, operators), 0])

# Random
for i in range(0, numRandom):
 newMembersWithError.append([gtr.getTree(minHeight, maxHeight, minValue,  maxValue, variables, operators), 0])

# Copy
members = self.getMembersForReproduction(numCopy, 0.3)
for m in members:
 newMembersWithError.append([m.clone(), 0])

 self.membersWithErrors = newMembersWithError

 # No side effects
 def pruneTreeForMaxHeight(tree, maxHeight, minValue, maxValue,   variables):
 """ Returns a new tree that is like the specified tree
 but pruned so that its height is maxHeight """
 def pruneTreeAux(tree, maxHeight, counter, minValue, maxValue,    variables):
 if tree.height() == 1:
    return tree.clone()
 if counter == maxHeight:
    return gtr.getLeaf(minValue, maxValue, variables)
pruned1 = pruneTreeAux(tree.op1, maxHeight, counter + 1, minValue, maxValue, variables)
  pruned2 = pruneTreeAux(tree.op2, maxHeight, counter + 1, minValue, maxValue, variables)
   return tr.BinaryOperatorInternalNode(tree.operator, pruned1, pruned2)
  return pruneTreeAux(tree, maxHeight, 1, minValue, maxValue, variables)

# Crossover
for i in range(0, numCrossover):
 members = self.getMembersForReproduction(2, 0.3)
 m1 = members[0]
 m2 = members[1]
 newMember = trop.crossover(m1, m2)
 if shouldPruneForMaxHeight and newMember.height() > maxHeight:
 newMember = trop.pruneTreeForMaxHeight(newMember, maxHeight, minValue,    maxValue, variables)
 newMembersWithError.append([newMember, 0])
```

The numCrossover is already defined. What I am missing here?

Comment: Is your indentation exactly as shown here? Because there are a lot of problems with it.

Comment: is the `for i in range(0, numCrossover):` block *inside* the `next` function definition?

Comment: is the loop also in pruneTreeForMaxHeight()?

Comment: I'm guessing there's some function scope that isn't being defined properly here. Your last crossover loop looks like you are doing that in global scope, but `numCrossover` is a function-local variable

Comment: is `line 105` at the same indentation level as `line 67`? `line 67`, same variable but has no error..

Comment: This was a mess so I copied and pasted parts from the url provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 117 your for loop with the comment # Crossover is out of scope of the definition inside next()

```
import random as rnd
import generator as gtr
import treeOperations as trop

class Generation(object):
    def __init__(self):
      self.membersWithErrors = []

def addMember(self, member):
  """ Add a tree to the generation """
  self.membersWithErrors.append([member, 0])

def setMember(self, member, index):
   """ Updates the member at the specified position """
   self.membersWithErrors[index] = member

def setError(self, index, error):
    """ Sets the error of the member at the specified position """
    self.membersWithErrors[index][1] = error

def getMember(self, index):
    """ Returns the member at the specified position """
    return self.membersWithErrors[index][0]

def getError(self, index):
    """ Returns the error of the member at the specified position """
    return self.membersWithErrors[index][1]

def size(self):
    """ Returns the number of members curently in the generation """
    return len(self.membersWithErrors)

def clear(self):
    """ Clears the generation, i.e. removes all the members """
    self.membersWithErrors.clear()

def sort(self, descending):
    """ Sorts the members of the generation according the their score """
    self.membersWithErrors.sort(key = lambda l: l[1], reverse = descending)

def getMembersForReproduction(self, numMembers, pickProb):
    """ Returns a certain number of distinct members from the generation.
    The first member is selected with probability pickProb. If it's not          chosen, the
    second member is selected with probability pickProb, and so on. """
    selectedMembers = []
    while len(selectedMembers) < numMembers:
      indexSelected = 0
      while rnd.randint(0, 100) > int(pickProb * 100) and indexSelected != len(self.membersWithErrors) - 1:
        indexSelected += 1
        memberWithErrorSelected = self.membersWithErrors[indexSelected]
        if memberWithErrorSelected[0] not in selectedMembers:
           selectedMembers.append(memberWithErrorSelected[0])
    return selectedMembers

def next(self, crossoverPerc, mutationPerc, randomPerc, copyPerc, shouldPruneForMaxHeight, minHeight, maxHeight, minValue, maxValue, variables, operators):
    """ It proceeds to the next generation with the help of genetic operations """
    oldMembersWithError = self.membersWithErrors
    newMembersWithError = []
    maxMembers = len(oldMembersWithError)

    numCrossover = int(maxMembers * crossoverPerc)
    numMutation = int(maxMembers * mutationPerc)
    numRandom = int(maxMembers * randomPerc)
    numCopy = maxMembers - numCrossover - numMutation - numRandom

    # Crossover
    for i in range(0, numCrossover):
        members = self.getMembersForReproduction(2, 0.3)
        m1 = members[0]
        m2 = members[1]
        newMember = trop.crossover(m1, m2)
        newMembersWithError.append([newMember, 0])

    # Mutation
    for i in range(0, numMutation):
        m1 = self.getMembersForReproduction(1, 0.3)[0]
        newMembersWithError.append([trop.mutation(m1, minValue, maxValue, variables, operators), 0])

    # Random
    for i in range(0, numRandom):
        newMembersWithError.append([gtr.getTree(minHeight, maxHeight, minValue, maxValue, variables, operators), 0])

    # Copy
    members = self.getMembersForReproduction(numCopy, 0.3)
    for m in members:
        newMembersWithError.append([m.clone(), 0])

    self.membersWithErrors = newMembersWithError

# No side effects
def pruneTreeForMaxHeight(tree, maxHeight, minValue, maxValue, variables):
    """ Returns a new tree that is like the specified tree
    but pruned so that its height is maxHeight """
    def pruneTreeAux(tree, maxHeight, counter, minValue, maxValue, variables):
        if tree.height() == 1:
            return tree.clone()
        if counter == maxHeight:
            return gtr.getLeaf(minValue, maxValue, variables)
        pruned1 = pruneTreeAux(tree.op1, maxHeight, counter + 1, minValue, maxValue, variables)
        pruned2 = pruneTreeAux(tree.op2, maxHeight, counter + 1, minValue, maxValue, variables)
        return tr.BinaryOperatorInternalNode(tree.operator, pruned1, pruned2)
    return pruneTreeAux(tree, maxHeight, 1, minValue, maxValue, variables)

def pruneTreeAux(tree, maxHeight, counter, minValue, maxValue,    variables):
    if tree.height() == 1:
        return tree.clone()
    if counter == maxHeight:
        return gtr.getLeaf(minValue, maxValue, variables)
        pruned1 = pruneTreeAux(tree.op1, maxHeight, counter + 1, minValue, maxValue, variables)
        pruned2 = pruneTreeAux(tree.op2, maxHeight, counter + 1, minValue, maxValue, variables)
        return tr.BinaryOperatorInternalNode(tree.operator, pruned1, pruned2)
    return pruneTreeAux(tree, maxHeight, 1, minValue, maxValue, variables)

# Crossover
for i in range(0, numCrossover):
    members = self.getMembersForReproduction(2, 0.3)
    m1 = members[0]
    m2 = members[1]
    newMember = trop.crossover(m1, m2)
    if shouldPruneForMaxHeight and newMember.height() > maxHeight:
        newMember = trop.pruneTreeForMaxHeight(newMember, maxHeight, minValue,    maxValue, variables)
        newMembersWithError.append([newMember, 0])
```